# How to multiply every element of a vector individually by a single value in R

Tags: r, vector

Sorry for the super basic question, am new here and to coding:

For example I have a vector: `v <- c(12, 26, 77, 54)` and I want to multiply each element by 100 so the output will be `c(1200, 2600, 7700, 5400)`.

How would I go about this?

Have tried using 'prod' function and "*"

Answer (score 2):

Just multiply the whole vector by 100:

```
v <- c(12, 26, 77, 54) * 100
v
[1] 1200 2600 7700 5400
```